# compare two variable with same value returns false

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel macro I have the following statement:

```
mese= 6 'from excel cell
mese_tgt = 6 'from input box
quindicina =1 'from excel cell
quindicina_tgt = 1 'from input box

If mese = mese_tgt And quindicina = quindicina_tgt Then
'do stuff here
End If
```

This will always return false. If I debug i see that the values are correctly assigned so that I have

```
If 6 = 6 And 1 = 1 Then
```

What am I missing? For what I know vba doesn't require == for comparison but maybe I am wrong?

EDIT: I do not declare the variables but just do:

```
mese_tgt = InputBox("Che mese vuoi elaborare?", "Scegli il mese")
quindicina_tgt = InputBox("Quale quindicina vuoi elaborare? 1 o 2", "Scegli la quindicina")
mese = sh2.Range("B" & riga).Value
quindicina = sh2.Range("C" & riga).Value
```

Comment: How are the variables declared?

Comment: If I declare all as long works fine.

Comment: @ScottCraner edited the question with how I build the variables

Comment: are you saying that = is a strict comparison operator? Like === in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:

> `mese_tgt = InputBox("Che mese vuoi elaborare?", "Scegli il mese")`

is returning a string and not a number.  In Excel `"1" <> 1`  So you must declare your variable so VBA does not guess to the type:

```
Dim mese as Long, mese_tgt as Long, quindicina as Long, quindicina_tgt as Long
```

Now VBA will not guess the type and it will force the result as a Long.

One Note Long are integers only, no decimals.  If your numbers have decimals then use `Double` instead of `Long`

One should get in the habit of always declaring their variables.

Comment: Have to do plus 1 for the last line alone ! Really warrants its own post...

Comment: thanks. I am more familiar with PHP and JS where = is assignment == is comparison and "6"==6 is true and ===is a strict comparison where "6"===6 will be false. Ah! and you don't declare your variables types (there is not such a concept in php). So good to know!